# Guice - what is the equivalent of Spring Autowired in Guice

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, guice

I am trying to use Guice and I am coming from Spring.

I am wondering if `@Inject` is the equivalent of `@Autowired` in Spring and if I can use it in web application exactly as I am using it in Spring.

Imagine I have a Facade which depends on a service, in Spring I can define a bean for that service and then when the server starts up I can get the instance of the service inside my facade.

```
class FacadeImpl{
  @Autowire Service service;
  ...
}
```

Assume that service has a concrete implementation and in Spring will automatically inject it.

Does Guice has a similar approach? can I do something like

```
class Facade{
  @Inject Service service;
}
```

or is it a magic that only spring does?

In my web application, I am starting embedded tomcat and I used google guice modules in such a way

```
Guice.createInjector(new ConfigurationModule());
```

hoping that this will be enough to "inject" whatever is annotated with `@Inject`.

However, it is not working ( I am not surprised ).
Can you guys help me to figure out which are the BP to inject dependencies on my Servlets or Facades etc..?

Answer (score 2):

## Yes, `@Inject` can act as `@Autowired`... given some conditions.

Guice doesn't require `Module`s, though they're very often used. So you can get rid of them if you want to.

If your class is a concrete class, you can directly `@Inject` it, just like `@Autowired`, but you also probably have to mark the class `@Singleton` because the default scope in Guice is not singleton, but a new instance everyone, unlike Spring.

Guice is not Spring, but the most important features of one are present in the other.

### Using Guice with Tomcat

When you want to use Guice with Tomcat, there is very little configuration to do, but there is still configuration. You will require a `Module`, but only the servlet.

In your **`web.xml`**, add the following:

```xml
<listener>
  <listener-class>path.to.MyGuiceServletConfig</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
  <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**`MyGuiceServletConfig.java`**

```java
public class MyGuiceServletConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener {
  @Override protected Injector getInjector() {
    return Guice.createInjector(new ServletModule() {
      @Override protected void configureServlets() {
        serve("/*").with(MyServlet.class); // Nothing else is needed.
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**`MyServlet.java`**

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Inject // Similar to @Autowired
  private MyService myService;

  @Override public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.getWriter().write(myService.hello("Guice"));
  }
}
```

Now you have a choice with `MyService`: either you make an interface out of it and you have to define, and bind an implementation, or you make a concrete class out of it.

#### `MyService` as an interface

**`MyService.java`**

```
@ImplementedBy(MyServiceImpl.class) // This says "hey Guice, the default implementation is MyServiceImpl."
public interface MyService {
  String hello(String name);
}
```

**`MyServiceImpl.java`**

```
@Singleton // Use the same default scope as Spring
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
  // @Inject dependencies as you wish.
  public String hello(String name) { return "Hello, " + name + "!"; }
}
```

If you want to avoid the `@ImplementedBy`, you can still use your module above, and add `bind(MyService.class).to(MyServiceImpl.class).in(Scopes.SINGLETON);`, or write a provider method in the same `Module`:

```
@Provides @Singleton MyService provideMyService() {
  return new MyServiceImpl();
}
```

#### `MyService` as a concrete class

**`MyService.java`**

```
@Singleton // Use the same default scope as Spring
public class MyService {
  // @Inject dependencies as you wish.
  public String hello(String name) { return "Hello, " + name + "!"; }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is very interesting, do you have a concrete example by any chance? I have looked around tutorials but seems all of them wants me to use modules and use it in main methods.

Comment: @OEH Here's your example, as requested.

Comment: Thank you for that, I will try this solution this evening! I am using embedded tomcat so I don t have web.xml, however I am sure I can add servlets in tomcat pojo via doing tomcat.addServlet or equivalent, thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

In Guice, there is no direct equivalent of the `@Autowired` Spring annotation. Dependency injection usage is explained in the [Getting started page](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GettingStarted).

1) You have to annotate the constructor of your service with the `@Inject` annotation:

```
 @Inject
  BillingService(CreditCardProcessor processor, 
      TransactionLog transactionLog) {
    this.processor = processor;
    this.transactionLog = transactionLog;
  }
```

2) Then define the bindings between types and implementations in a module:

```
public class BillingModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override 
  protected void configure() {

     /*
      * This tells Guice that whenever it sees a dependency on a TransactionLog,
      * it should satisfy the dependency using a DatabaseTransactionLog.
      */
    bind(TransactionLog.class).to(DatabaseTransactionLog.class);

     /*
      * Similarly, this binding tells Guice that when CreditCardProcessor is used in
      * a dependency, that should be satisfied with a PaypalCreditCardProcessor.
      */
    bind(CreditCardProcessor.class).to(PaypalCreditCardProcessor.class);
  }
}
```

3) And finally build an injector and use it:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*
     * Guice.createInjector() takes your Modules, and returns a new Injector
     * instance. Most applications will call this method exactly once, in their
     * main() method.
     */
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new BillingModule());

    /*
     * Now that we've got the injector, we can build objects.
     */
    BillingService billingService = injector.getInstance(BillingService.class);
    ...
  }
```